# Mysql Trigger with Transaction Lock

Tags: mysql, locking

I am trying to add a trigger to update auto voucher no in my journal_summary table. Also to prevent duplication trying to add a transaction locking. Below is my trigger so far. It is working fine without the transaction locking. As I add the lock it is giving error `Transaction characteristics can not be changed while a transaction is in progress` - not a single insert can be committed after adding the lock.

I have also check if any current transaction with this query but its zero results. `SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use > 0;`

what's wrong I am doing

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_journal_no
BEFORE INSERT ON journal_summary
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
        DECLARE v_count INT;
        DECLARE v_journal_no VARCHAR(15);
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- set the isolation level to serializable to use row-level locks
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 INTO v_count FROM journal_summary WHERE JournalDate = NEW.JournalDate AND concern_id = NEW.concern_id FOR UPDATE; -- use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE to lock the selected rows
         IF v_count > 99999 THEN -- exceeding 5 digits
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot insert record: Too many journals for this date and concern.';
         END IF;
         SET v_journal_no = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NEW.JournalDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), '-', LPAD(v_count, 5, '0'));
         UPDATE journal_summary SET journal_no = v_journal_no WHERE id = NEW.id; -- update the journal_no column with the calculated value
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is explicit in this case: you cannot change the transaction isolation level when you are in the middle of an open transaction and a trigger is always in the middle of an open transaction.

As serializable isolation level basically transforms all simple selects to select ... for update locking reads and you already use a locking read, I do not think you need to change your transaction isolation level at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I am using a count function to update sl, if another user access at the same time- he will get the same count. So, is not there a chance both user is getting same count and thus occurs a duplicate

Comment: For update clause places an exclusive lock on the rows affected by the query using the count function. Another query, that wants to place an exclusive lock on the same rows, must wait until the first exclusive lock is released. This is the whole point of locking!

Comment: That means I can safely remove this line `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- set the isolation level to serializable to use row-level locks`

Comment: You have no choice, but to remove that line as it will never work within a transaction - see the error message

Comment: I have removed this from the trigger , Trying only with `FOR UPDATE`, Now it is giving error  `Unable to process mysql query- can't update table journal_summary in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`

Comment: That's a completely different question which has already been answered here on SO several times: use NEW.column_name = ... form to change a value in the newly inserted row.